# Positional argument using argparse in a specific scenario

Tags: python, windows, command-line-arguments, argparse, optional-parameters

Currently I am trying to make something in Python.So the command line would look something like this when I run the program (main.py):

**main.py --optionalargument1 value1 value2 value3 --optionalargument2 value 1 value 2 value 3 --optionalargument3 value1 value2 value3**

So, my problem is when I run this program the last value always needs to be taken as a positional argument and not as another value for lets say optionalargument3 if I am using it. How do I do that?

Each optionalargument can have any number of values.
So:
main.py -optionalargument1 value1 value2 value3 value4

If I run this I would want value4 to be taken as a separate positional argument and not grouped with the optional argument. I am sorry if this is basic but I am new to programming.

I tried nargs and other options when creating the positional argument.

Comment: You have to supply the `positional` before any of the `*` optionals.  `main.py value4 -optionalargument1 value1 value2 value3`. The `*` is greedy, taking all strings that it can get - up to the end or the next flag ('--') string.  It does not look ahead and reserve a string for the `positional`.

Comment: This is a common issue... the solution is to either force positional arguments to be supplied prior to options that take nargs or to manually check the last argument yourself

Answer (score -1):

This task can be solved using `argparse` module.

Python documentation at https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html describes how to parse arguments with any number of values fed into command line.